# mvc .htaccess not understanding how to setup 1 level below root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Learning mvc here, so simple answers would help.

My site directory is 1 level below the actual web root, "mvc"

root/mvc

I have one .htaccess file in the mvc directory. root/mvc/.htaccess

```
<IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule *$ webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule {.*} webroot /$1 [L]
```

In the webroot directory, root/mvc/webroot I have a second htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT, L]
```

And I also have an index.php in root/mvc/webroot,

```
<?php

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

print_r($uri);
```

Now according to the tutorial I should be able to type into a web browser url

http://localhost/mvc/controller/action/param1/param2

and index.php should echo

controller/action/param1/param2

except I'm getting a 404 error

The requested URL /mvc/controller/action/param1/param2 was not found on this server.

Clearly I'm not getting the fundamentals on the redirect of the web request, but have no idea why.

TIA folks, this one has me dazed and confused.

Oops there are closing  tags on both the htaccess files.

Comment: `[PT, L]` is a syntax error, it should be `[PT,L]` But if you didn't get `500` that means your htaccess is not enabled or not it correct path.

Comment: @anubhava, made the change, thanks for the answer, but still getting the same error. The tutorial I'm following has the first .htaccess in the web root but I have other projects running so am I level down, wondering if this is having some weird effect.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?